# configure tomcat in Linux and run deployed application

Tags: java, linux, tomcat

I want to start tomcat on command prompt in linux and want to run deployed application in tomcat.Linux is new for me i have done same thing in window. Can i know step for start and run application in tomcat for linux ?

I have learn about set environment variable but for linux where to set that i don't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this [step-by-step guide](http://www.puschitz.com/InstallingTomcat.html)

Answer (score 0):

depending on your version, the tomcat docs are fairly concise.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/setup.html

Is there a specific problem?

[EDIT] So possibly not great, but unzip, go to the TOMCAT/bin directory and run ./startup.sh

Answer (score 0):

Once you setuped your Tomcat, you can open the URL of localhost:8080 and you will get to the administration panel. There you can deploy '*.war' files- you can simply export your webapp in Eclipse and upload it there.